# How to Remove Duplicate Matches in a MatchCollection

Tags: c#, regex, duplicates, match

In my MatchCollection, I get matches of the same thing. Like this:

```
string text = @"match match match";
Regex R = new Regex("match");
MatchCollection M = R.Matches(text);
```

How does one remove duplicate matches and is it the fastest way possible?

*Assume "duplicate" here means that the match contains the exact same string.*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Linq

If you are using .Net 3.5 or greater such as 4.7, linq can be used to remove the duplicates of the match.

```
string data = "abc match match abc";

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", 

Regex.Matches(data, @"([^\s]+)")
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select (m => m.Groups[0].Value)
     .Distinct()

));

// Outputs abc, match
```

---

### .Net 2 or No Linq

Place it into a hastable then extract the strings:

```
string data = "abc match match abc";

MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(data, @"[^\s]+");

Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();

foreach (Match mt in mc)
{
    string foundMatch = mt.ToString();
    if (hash.Contains(foundMatch) == false)
        hash.Add(foundMatch, string.Empty);

}

// Outputs abc and match.
foreach (DictionaryEntry element in hash)
    Console.WriteLine (element.Key);
```

Comment: Note it displays the text in order...duplicate text matches are removed after the initial find.

Comment: Why do you need to use m.Groups[0].Value? Why can't we just use m.Value?

Comment: Its a habit I prefer to keep. `m.Value` is correct in most situations (when dealing with regex) but one must understand that `[0]` is the whole match group, while `[1]` ...`[n]` are separate sub captures *within the group*.  Sometimes you may have a pattern for `a(b)c` where `m.Value` and `m.Groups[0].value` are "abc", but one needs just "b" (because its in the match capture grouping) one uses`m.Groups[1].value`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"\b(?<word>\w+)\s+(\k<word>)\b", RegexOptions.Compiled);
string text = @"match match match";
MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);
```

Comment: What if the string is only "match"?

Comment: If the regex pattern is used only once, the compiled flag does nothing for the user. Better to use the static method Regex.Matches() which will automatically cache a pattern if used mutiple times.