# How can i store each individual regex match for a hashtag in my list?

Tags: c#, regex

When looping through the matched results from the regex, i create a new hashtag object and save it into a list.

The problem is, if i have 4 #hashtags, its the last hashtag that is recorded 4 times. eg - #this #is #some #hashtags. #hashtags would be recorded 4 times in my list. How can i get all the hashtags recorded properly in my list?

```
List<Hashtag> hashTags = new List<Hashtag>();
                        var hashTag = new Hashtag();

                        Regex expression = new Regex(@"([#][a-zA-Z0-9]{1})\w*");
                        var results = expression.Matches(model.Caption);
                        foreach (Match match in results)
                        {
                            hashTag.CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
                            hashTag.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                            hashTag.Text = match.ToString();

                            hashTags.Add(hashTag);
                        }

                        db.Hashtags.AddRange(hashTags);
                        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

my list hashTags should should contain every individual hashtag from the matched results.

Comment: Move the declaration of your HashTag variable to inside the loop, `var hashTag = new Hashtag();`

Comment: @SimonWilson Awesome, not all heroes wear capes. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the line `var hashTag = new Hashtag();` within the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Hashtag> hashTags = new List<Hashtag>();
// var hashTag = new Hashtag(); remove this line move it to inside foreach

Regex expression = new Regex(@"([#][a-zA-Z0-9]{1})\w*");
var results = expression.Matches(model.Caption);
foreach (Match match in results)
{
   /*Keep it here so every time a new instance of Hashtag will be created and cached in your hasTags list,
  instead of updating same reference and adding it again, which causes your issue */
  var hashTag = new Hashtag();
  hashTag.CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
  hashTag.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
  hashTag.Text = match.ToString();

  hashTags.Add(hashTag);
}

db.Hashtags.AddRange(hashTags);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Before creating the `HashTag` instances remove all duplicates:

```
string data = "#this #is #some #hashtags. #hashtags";

var tags = 
Regex.Matches(data, @"#([^\W]+)")
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
     .Distinct()
     .ToList();
```

Which returns a list looking like this:

[image]

So once that concept is understood, use the `Select` Linq extension (*which is considered a "projection" because it "projects" to something new*) to actually return a `List<HashTag>` and not even need a `for` loop such as

```
List<HashTag> hashTags =
    Regex.Matches(data, @"#([^\W]+)")
         .OfType<Match>()
         .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
         .Distinct()
         .Select(tag => new HashTag
                        {
                            CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
                            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                            Text = tag
                        })
        .ToList();
```

which looks like this:

[image]

---

This is based on my answer

[How to Remove Duplicate Matches in a MatchCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8597251/285795)